# jQuery select from list

Tags: jquery

I have the following list:

```
<select id="id1">
    <option value="">Firstone</option>
    <option value="1">Secondone</option>
    <option value="2">Thirdone</option>
</select>
```

I did the following to select "Secondone" from the list:

```
$("#id1").val("1").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This didn't seem to select it.

**How can I select "Secondone" from the list?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the selected value of a list you just need to use the `val()` `function`, no need to set the attribute for selected.

Example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWEQU/)

```
$('#id1').val('1');
```

If you're trying to literally get the element that is currently selected, you can do this:

```
var selectedElement = $("#id1").find(":selected");
```

Comment: He didn't say he's trying to set the value. He's trying to choose that option... that's a different thing.

Comment: Hello redlena, Gabe's solution is correct, since it's a select box.

Comment: @redlena, Setting the value chooses that option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want: `$("#id1 option[value='1']").attr('selected', 'selected');`